# Probability of a random variable and its counterpart raised to power of $n$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-explanation

I came across few situations where they stated that the probability of a random variable is equal to the probability of its square root (case1) or its square (case 2). My questions are:

1. How could the equalities be derived, based on what logic?
2. Can I make a general statement that the probability of a random variable is equal to its counterpart raised to the power of $n$ where $n$ is any real number, that is, $$\mathbb{P}(X \leq a) = \mathbb{P}(X^n \leq a^n)$$

**Case 1**:

[image]

**Case 2**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that anything appearing inside a $P(\cdot)$ is an event. More precisely, this means that if the random variables are defined on a probability space $\Omega$, then an event $A$ is a subset of $\Omega$ and $P(A)$ depends only on the the set of elements of $A$ (and not on how a description of $A$ appears).

Going back to your question, in both cases we have two descriptions of the same event. In the first case we have the event
$$
A=\Biggl\{\omega\in\Omega\colon \frac{(X(\omega)-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}\geq t^2\Biggr\},
$$
which is equal to the event
$$
B=\Bigl\{\omega\in\Omega\colon |X(\omega)-\mu|\geq t\sigma\Bigr\},
$$
since if $\omega\in B$ then by squaring we see that $\omega\in A$, and conversely. The reasoning is similar in the second example as well.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation which helps people who are not strong in Statistics understand the underlying issue. Much appreciated. Could you also please help with question 2 ($\mathbb{P}(X \leq a) = \mathbb{P}(X^n \leq a^n)$ before I can accept your answer?

Comment: Given what I have already said, your second question boils down to something that does not involve probability or statistics. You are trying to find out whether the conditions $X\leq a$ and $X^n\leq a^n$ are equivalent. They are not, in general - for example, $-2\leq 1$ but $(-2)^2>(1)^2$. The other answer gave conditions under which they are equivalent. If you have more confusion on this point I would strongly suggest asking it in a separate question (or better yet, searching the site since the same question has undoubtedly been already asked before).

Answer (score 1):

For $x,y\ge 0$ and $a>0$, $x\le y$ iff $x^a\le y^a$. Therefore, for a nonnegative random variable $X$, 
$$
\{X\le y\} =\{X^a\le y^a\}.
$$